# Entity Framework : Is it possible to inherit from base configuration class?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am modeling a new database by EF CodeFirst. Here I have an abstract base class and every domain model inherited from this class:

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public byte [] TimeStamp { get; set; }
}
```

And there a lot of classes like :

```
public class Country : Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string InternationalCode { get; set; }
    public Location Location { get; set; }
    public ICollection<City> Cities { get; set; }

    public Country(string name, string internationalCode, decimal latitude, decimal longitude) 
        : this(name, internationalCode)
    {
        Location.Latitude = latitude;
        Location.Longitude = longitude;
    }
    public Country(string name, string internationalCode) : this()
    {
        Name = name;
        InternationalCode = internationalCode;
    }

    public Country()
    {
        Location = new Location();
        Cities = new List<City>();
    }
}
```

And every model's configuration based on FluentAPI :

```
public CountryConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(p => p.Id);
        Property(p => p.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        Property(p => p.TimeStamp).IsRowVersion();

        Property(p => p.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(100);
        Property(p => p.InternationalCode).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(5);

        HasMany(p => p.Cities)
            .WithOptional(p => p.BelongedCountry)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.BelongedCountryId);
    }
```

The problem is that

```
        HasKey(p => p.Id);
        Property(p => p.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        Property(p => p.TimeStamp).IsRowVersion();
```

**this piece copy-pasted more than 30+ times for each domain model.** Is there any way to make Configuration classes inherit from **EntityTypeConfiguration** but also inherit\contain configuration from Entity Configuration?

```
public class EntityConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Entity>
{
    public EntityConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(p => p.Id);
        Property(p => p.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        Property(p => p.TimeStamp).IsRowVersion();
    }
}
```

I know, that C# doesn't allow multiple inheritance. What can you suggest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, can't you use an abstract class?

```
public abstract class BaseEntityConfiguration<T> : EntityTypeConfiguration<T> where T : Entity 
{
  protected BaseEntityConfiguration()
  {
      HasKey(p => p.Id);
      Property(p => p.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
      Property(p => p.TimeStamp).IsRowVersion();
  }
}

public class CountryConfiguration : BaseEntityConfiguration<Country>
{}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just from looking at your snippets, and how I could structure it to meet your requirements, I might alter your EntityConfiguration class like so:

```
public class EntityConfiguration<TEntityType> : EntityTypeConfiguration<TEntityType> where TEntityType : Entity
{
  public EntityConfiguration()
  {
    HasKey(p => p.Id);
    Property(p => p.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
    Property(p => p.TimeStamp).IsRowVersion();
  }
}
```

Then, you could create inherited configurations, like your CountryConfiguration:

```
public class CountryConfiguration : EntityConfiguration<Country>
{
  public CountryConfiguration() : base()
  {
    Property(p => p.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(100);
    Property(p => p.InternationalCode).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(5);
  }
}
```

By restricting the generic type on the EntityConfiguration class with the where clause to your base Entity type, you'll be able to work with those base properties in the EntityConfiguration class, while leaving the rest to the derived classes for your specific models.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate solutions provided by @mxmissile and @Jodacola, you done exactly what I was looking for.

I just want to add that I found another "bug" way to do what I asked :

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Entity>().HasKey(p => p.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Entity>().Property(p => p.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Entity>().Property(p => p.TimeStamp).IsRowVersion();

        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CountryConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CityConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new LocationConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.ComplexType<Location>();
```

It is "not appropriate" solution and I just publish it in academic purposes. 
For some reasons, it created a table "Entities" in the database. I would be very gratheful, if you could explain, why here created a table "Entities" in db?

In db it contains copy of all Id's from all entities inherited from Entity class.

Comment: You should ask a new question for this. But you should not need the first 3 lines of that code. Since your config classes inherit from base config class.

Comment: @mxmissile, nope, here I use "normal" config classes without inheritance applied. I will follow you advice and ask another question.